# Dynamically changing tooltip text of checkbox in angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I have this code and I need to pass the text to the tooltip whether checkbox is active or not, so this will display eg. "active" when checkbox is active and "disactive" when not. How to do that?

```
<div class="wifi__switcher switcher">
    <input type="checkbox" [id]="wifiIdentifier" class="input switcher--input js-checkbox"  [checked]="activated" (click)="saveState()">
    <label class="switcher--label" [for]="wifiIdentifier"  matTooltipPosition="above" matTooltip="(tooltipMessageAccordingToCheckboxState)">Toggle</label>
    <!--</div>-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqley5)

HTML:

```
<div class="wifi__switcher switcher">
    <input type="checkbox"  class="input switcher--input js-checkbox" [checked]="activated" (change)="saveState($event)">
  {{activated}}
    <label  matTooltipPosition="above" matTooltip="{{activated?'activated': 'not active'}}">Toggle</label>

</div>
```

TS:

```
activated: boolean = false;

  saveState(ev){
    if(ev.target.checked){
      this.activated = true
    } else{
      this.activated = false
    }
  }
```

Comment: From my understanding of the question this should be marked as the correct answer. It worked well for me. Thanks @Aashish!